# How do I switch active tab in slider with Jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a tabbed slider that's supposed to change the color of the active tab. The tabs switch properly, but for some reason, I can't get it to change the active class over. Below is the HTML and JS.

I know I'm calling something improperly to make the classes switch in the tabs, but I'm not sure what it should be

Link to demo site: http://atlanticdatasecurity.digitalpreviewsite.com/

**HTML**

```
<div class="home-hero container-fluid p-0">

<div id="heroCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
   <!-- <div class="background-overlay"></div> -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="background-overlay hidden"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="hero-inner-content offset-md-2 col-md-8">
                        <?php echo get_field('hero_section_one'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="background-overlay hidden"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="hero-inner-content offset-md-2 col-md-8">
                        <?php echo get_field('hero_section_two'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="background-overlay hidden"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="hero-inner-content offset-md-2 col-md-8">
                        <?php echo get_field('hero_section_three'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


   <!-- <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#heroCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fal fa-long-arrow-alt-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#heroCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fal fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i>
    </a>-->
    <div class="slider-tabs">
        <div data-target="#heroCarousel" class="click-nav tab slick-slide active" data-slide-to="0"><span>Support Aware® & Service Desk</span></div>
        <div data-target="#heroCarousel" class="click-nav tab slick-slide" data-slide-to="1"><span>Cybersecurity Solutions</span></div>
        <div data-target="#heroCarousel" class="click-nav tab slick-slide" data-slide-to="2"><span>Training Courses</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="slick-dots">
    <li class="click-nav slick-active">
        <button type="button" id="slick-slide-control00" data-target="#heroCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</button>
    </li>
    <li class="click-nav">
        <button type="button" id="slick-slide-control01" data-target="#heroCarousel" data-slide-to="1">2</button>
    </li>
    <li class="click-nav">
        <button type="button" id="slick-slide-control02" data-target="#heroCarousel" data-slide-to="2">3</button>
    </li>

</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#heroCarousel').carousel({
        interval:   250000
    });

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#heroCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
        clickEvent = true;
        $('.click-nav').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because "`.carousel-indicators`" are undefined bs can't find it.

Can you try again by adding "`.carousel-indicators`" to the `<div>` element with the class "`.slider-tabs`"? There will probably be some shifts with the newly added class, but we can write some additional code to override later.

```
<div class="slider-tabs carousel-indicators">
```

It looks like you are also using **Slick Slider** outside of the **bootstrap carousel**.

Using both classes in the same carousel may cause conflicts.
If adding the above class fails, you can try deleting the "`.click-nav`" and "`.slick-slide`" classes.

If the problem is not resolved, we can start thinking **different things**.

Comment: that did it! Thanks so much